# How to apply a jQuery event handler to multiple cached selectors?

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery-selectors, jquery

Lets say I have three buttons

```
<button data-action="grow" class="resizeButton">Grow</button>
<button data-action="shrink" class="resizeButton">Shrink</button>
<button id="normalButton">Normal Button</button>
```

I have the buttons in variables

```
var $normalButton = $('#normalButton');
var $growButton = $('.resizeButton[data-action="grow"]');
var $shrinkButton = $('.resizeButton[data-action="shrink"]');
```

Now lets say I want to hook up a `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`, and `click` event handler to the normal button

```
$normalButton.on({
   mouseenter: function(){
       //do some stuff
   },

   mouseleave: function(){
       //reverse some stuff
   },

   click: function(){
       //do some more stuff
   }
});
```

The magical jQuery wizards make this work for us.

Now lets say we want to append a `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`, and `click` event handler to the grow button and the shrink button. The same handlers for those buttons, but different handlers to the normal button.

There are a couple of ways I can see to do this, but they are all basically the same idea, just assign them twice, once to the first button, once to the next button.

So,

```
var handlers = {
    mouseenter: function(){
        //do some different stuff
    },

    mouseleave: function(){
        //reverse some different stuff
    },

    click: function(){
        //do some more different stuff
    }
};

$growButton.on(handlers);
$shrinkButton.on(handlers);
```

or

```
$.each([$growButton, $shrinkButton], function(i, el){
    el.on({
        mouseenter: function(){
            //do some different stuff
        },

        mouseleave: function(){
            //reverse some different stuff
        },

        click: function(){
            //do some more different stuff
        }
    });
});
```

But what I am wondering is if there is a syntax to create a jQuery object from, or just apply the handlers to a group of cached Selectors like `$([$growButton, $shrinkButton]).on(...` or similar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method:

```
$growButton.add($shrinkButton).on(...)
```

Comment: Adding to this, you may want your code more dynamically, for example, push all elements into an array and then apply the event to all of them. You can: simply use `$( arrayOfJqueryObjects )`.

Comment: @gustavohenke Why would you do that when you can just use `add`? Use something like `var jqObjs = $("#el1"); jqObjs.add($("#el2")); jqObjs.add($("#el3"));` - where, of course, the individual things passed to add would be existing jQuery objects in this case. It's much more maintable than dealing with an array as well.